# VBA Check max Length of cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to write a VBA code to check whether the length of all cells in a certain range remain under 25 characters.

If any of the cells will have more than 25 characters, a msgbox with the name of the cell needs to pop up..

For example the Range = A1:A10

If cell A3 then has 27 characters a msgbox needs to popup stating "Cell A3"

Can any of you guys help me out?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also what happens if Cell `A3` has 27 characters but Cell `A5` has 30? Do you only want the first error? Or do you want them combined into one `MsgBox` or should you have an individual `MsgBox` for each error. What's the desired behaviour?

Comment: Well still pretty new to VBA coding, so tried a lot and looked around online, but nothing solves my issue (or even remotely works..)

If multiple errors exist it would be great if they can be mentioned in the same message box.

Comment: @ErikSlui Please understand that people are here to help you with *your* code. They're not here to write that code for you. So you need to [edit] your question and add the code you have tried and tell us where you got stuck or where you got errors. So anyone can show you what you did wrong and how to correct it in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is effectively what you're asking for. It's a very simple loop. It will however plague your screen on a large dataset with lots of values over 25

```
Sub TestCellLengths()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("A1:A10")
        If Len(c) > 25 Then MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    Next c
End Sub
```

I would recommend instead having only one `MsgBox` be displayed

```
Sub TestCellLengths()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Msg As String

    For Each c In Range("A1:A10")
        If Len(c) > 25 Then Msg = Msg & vbTab & c.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & vbNewLine
    Next c

    If Len(Msg) > 0 Then MsgBox "Cells:" & vbNewLine & Msg
End Sub
```

Comment: You can declare `Dim c As Range` so no need to use the *'evil'* variant here ;) Another advantage: you can use intelli sense on `c` then.